# Delphi Extended to C#

Tags: c#, delphi

how to convert a floating point 10 byte Hex string (Extended datatype in Delphi) to a C# datatype?

For example:
***00 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 ff 3f*** is at Delphi ***1***

Comment: I am not quire sure what you mean. Do you have a 10-byte buffer in a C# application containing a Delphi extended value, and want to convert it do a C# double value? If so, it can probably be done rather easily with pointers and some byte transfers.

Comment: First you will have to pick a type: double or decimal. The choice depends on the range and precision of your data. You'll always loose something.

Comment: Hi, sorry for some missing infos:
I have a hexadecimal string (created via delphi) which contains a floating point number (10 bytes -> data-type: extended).
Now I need to convert this bytes in a C# data-type like double. But double only have 8 bytes so if I use BitConverter.ToDouble() the result is not correct.

Comment: A delphi `extended` value is an IEEE Extended floating point.  It's specifications are here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision ... worst case you can twiddle the bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is my solution:

Every string contains a factor byte at the second position. In my example the factor is **ff**.

Now I have to convert the string via [Floating-Point Conversion](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/32bit.html) to decimal and multiply with the factor byte to get the result.

Example:
3f ff 80 00 00 (32bit) -> remove the factor byte (ff) -> 3f 80 00 00 -> convert to decimal -> result: 1 -> multiply with factor -> 1 * 1 -> result: **1**

I hope this was helpfully

Answer (score 2):

Was involved in same issue, sharing my solution somebody can find useful:

```
        var extendedSize = 10;
        var buf = new byte[extendedSize];

        // Populate buffer with something like: { 0x00, 0x68, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0xA2, 0x02, 0x40 } = 10.15
        // Read(buf, extendedSize);

        var sign = (buf[extendedSize - 1] & 0x80) == 0x80 ? -1 : 1;
        buf[extendedSize - 1] = (byte)(buf[extendedSize - 1] & 0x7F);
        var exp = BitConverter.ToUInt16(buf, extendedSize - 2);
        var integral = (buf[extendedSize - 3] & 0x80) == 0x80 ? 1 : 0;           

        // Calculate mantissa
        var mantissa = 0.0;
        var value = 1.0;
        var fractal = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buf, 0);

        while (fractal != 0)
        {
            value = value / 2;
            if ((fractal & 0x4000000000000000) == 0x4000000000000000) // Latest bit is sign, just skip it
            {
                mantissa += value;
            }
            fractal <<= 1;
        }

        return sign * (Math.Pow(2, exp - 16383)) * (integral + mantissa);
```

Code needs to be improved with NaN and Inf checks and probably "double" needs to be replaced by "decimal".

Comment: I edited this with a correction - discovered [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56736279/327083).